# Why won't my array of objects remove from the pie chart data point?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object, pie-chart

I've added a pie chart from CanvasJS. It comes with pre-existing data points which I've removed and I want to add my own data dynamically.

```
let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    interactivityEnabled: false,
    backgroundColor: "#272953",
    animationEnabled: false,
    title: {
        text: "Portfolio",
        fontColor: "#fff",
        fontFamily: "tahoma"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "pie",
        startAngle: 240,
        yValueFormatString: "##0\"%\"",
        indexLabel: "{label} {y}",
        dataPoints: [
            // { y: 79.45, label: "Google", indexLabelFontColor: "#fff", noOfUnits: 0, ticker: 'GOOGL' } <----- example
        ]
    }]
});

window.onload = loadPieChart();

function loadPieChart() {
    chart.render();
}

let dataPoints = chart.data[0].dataPoints;
```

So as I add a new stock, an object with data is pushed to `dataPoints`.

The problem I'm having is when I go to delete a stock, it removes itself from `dataPoints` which is fine 
but it still shows in the pie graph.

If you log `dataPoints` to the console, there's an empty array.

But if you log `chart.data[0].dataPoints`, it still has the previously added stocks in there.

For adding stocks:

```
dataPoints.push({ y: stockPercentage, 
   label: stockObject["name"], 
   indexLabelFontColor: "#fff", 
   noOfUnits: stockObject["noOfUnits"], 
   ticker: stockObject["ticker"] })
```

For deleting stocks:

```
function deleteStock(e) {

    //remove stock from Datapoint in pie chart    
    dataPoints = dataPoints.filter(stock => currentRow.childNodes[1].textContent !== stock['ticker']);

    chart.render();

}
```

Can't understand why it's adding and removing the objects in `dataPoints` but not removing in the pie graph and the fact that if you log `chart.data[0].dataPoints` , the data is still in there even after `let dataPoints = chart.data[0].dataPoints;`

I must be making a silly mistake.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in your `deleteStock` function :

```
chart.data[0].dataPoints = chart.data[0].dataPoints.filter(stock => currentRow.childNodes[1].textContent !== stock['ticker']);
```

since your `datapoints` array variable gets copy of `chart.data[0].dataPoints`, by removing object from `datapoint` would not remove it from the `chart.data[0].dataPoints`